# I want to convert html table values to variable in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, arrays

I have a html table below here is some values in table i want to store all values in variable in PHP For example <**tr>PAN No.ABCDE1234F I want $pan_number="ABCDE1234F";**
Like This All Please Help Anybody Can Tell Thank You Class Of Table Is tbl

`````
<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;align:center;"`enter code here`  class="tbl">    
                    <tr><th colspan="8" class="trHead">Income Tax Department Level PAN Query</th></tr>           
                    <tr>
                        <td class="labelsMIS" colspan="8">Enter Pan No :
                        <input type="text" name="selectedPan" value="" id="selectedPan" class="fe_1" onkeyup="makeUpper(this)"/>
                       <input type="submit" value="Search" id="genRepo" class="mybtn" onclick="return showDetails();"/>
 </td>
                    </tr>
          ````<div id="hideData">        
                
  
                    <tr><td colspan="4" class="stt">PAN Alloted Date</td><td colspan="4" class="sttb">11/03/2020</td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="4" class="stt">PAN No.</td><td colspan="4" class="sttb">ABCDE1234F</td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="4" class="stt">Applicant First Name</td><td colspan="4" class="sttb">FIRST NAME</td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="4" class="stt">Applicant MidName</td><td colspan="4" class="sttb"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="4" class="stt">Applicant SurName</td><td colspan="4" class="sttb">LAST NAME</td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="4" class="stt">Father's First Name</td><td colspan="4" class="sttb">FATHER FIRST NAME</td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="4" class="stt">Father's MidName</td><td colspan="4" class="sttb">FATHER MIDDLE NAME</td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="4" class="stt">Father's SurName</td><td colspan="4" class="sttb">FATHER LAST NAME</td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="4" class="stt">Gender</td><td colspan="4" class="sttb">Male</td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="4" class="stt">Applicant Category</td><td colspan="4" class="sttb">Individual Applicant</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="stt">Area Code</td><td class="sttb">&nbsp;LKN</td>
                    <td class="stt">Range Code</td><td class="sttb">&nbsp;72</td>
                    <td class="stt">AO Code</td><td class="sttb">&nbsp;4&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="stt">AO Type</td><td class="sttb">&nbsp;W&nbsp;</td></tr>
            
         </div>     
             </table> ````
`````

Comment: Are you doing web scraping?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

you should use Xpath.
first load content with DOMDocument class then use DOMXPath class to create query and extract values.
then you can assign those values to a variable.